# Create a one-row dataframe where every column is the same as an existing variable

Tags: r

I often write code like this:

```
answer.df = data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0), z = numeric(0))
for (i in 1:100) {
    x = do_stuff(i)
    y = do_more_stuff(i)
    z = yet_more_stuff(i)

    # Is there a better way of doing this:
    temp.df = data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z) 

    answer.df = rbind(answer.df, temp.df)
}
```

My question is, in the line `temp.df = data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z)`, **is there a neater way of doing this?**  Imagine it with ten or more variables to understand my problem.

Comment: not answering your problem directly, but, there is often (almost always) a better way of creating a data.frame than `rbind`-ing inside a `for` loop

Comment: Better *how*? You don't need to name the arguments to data frame - as long as you want the same names you can just do `data.frame(x, y, z)`.  If x, y, z were in a list rather than separate variables you could probably just use `as.data.frame`. But that line looks fine, really. It's the `rbind` line that looks awful: growing objects inside a loop like that is the [2nd Circle of Hell in the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Pre-allocate your `answer.df` and insert directly into that, or keep the vectors in lists and turn them into a data frame once at the end.

Comment: @SymbolixAU I'm just learning.  Baby steps.

Comment: @Gregor The thing you said about the lists looks good.  If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.  I'm not reading the 123-page paper you linked to, though.

Comment: Yes it's how everyone starts, I'm just trying to help you achieve your mission statement "on a mission to build a portfolio risk model in R without using a single for-loop" - ;)

Comment: @SymbolixAU Thanks.  I do hate those for-loops.  But they're all I have at the moment :(

Comment: I think a better approach is to re-design your function/requirements to use vectorised operations and completely move away from "often writing code like this". This will help you write better code in the long-run too.

Comment: @Gregor I've started reading your 123-page paper.  It's good.

Comment: It's quite good - reading it was my first step into learning how to write *good* R code. At first I thought "I'll read a chapter per week, and try to incorporate what I learn into my work," but pretty quickly I got impatient and finished it all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(1:100, function(i) list(x = xfun(i), y = yfun(i))))
```

Also try `rbindlist` from data.table which may have some performance advantages:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(1:100, function(i) list(x = xfun(i), y = yfun(i))))
```